# Xpath using CSS class names or getting locator using CSS

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

The web page has a set of radio buttons. Each radio button has a help icon which when clicked, gets a popup with help.
I am trying to get that help text using selenium webdriver.
So I want to get the text "HELP TEXT 2".
Please help with the construction of xpath or how to locate the help text using CSS. If there is a simpler way other than Xpath or CSS, please let me know.
I am using firefox and java binding for selenium.

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b" tabindex="0">
<input tabIndex="0" id="1">
<div class="c">
<label for="1"> apple </label>
<div class="d">
<span>Help</span>
</div>
<div class="f" role = "doc">
<div class="g">
<div class="h">
<button type="button" class="close"></button>
</div>
<div class="i" tabindex="0">
HELP TEXT 1
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
<div class="b" tabindex="0">
<input tabIndex="0" id="2">
<div class="c">
<label for="2"> orange </label>
<div class="d">
<span>Help</span>
</div>
<div class="f" role = "doc">
<div class="g">
<div class="h">
<button type="button" class="close"></button>
</div>
<div class="i" tabindex="0">
HELP TEXT 2
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying to get all help texts and to verify below answers will help you.. if you what to get HELP TEXT 2 straight forward //div[contains(text(),'HELP TEXT 2')] may helps you provided it returns only required element..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your requirement is not to find "HELP TEXT 2", which is trivial, but to find the help text associated with the button whose label is "close". If I've guessed wrong, please ignore this answer and take note when posting your next question.

If I'm right, it would be `//div[button[@class='close']]/following-sibling::div[1]`.

Comment: Michael, The requirement is that there is a "?" beside each radio button option. When I click on that "?" question mark, then I will get a small popup window that has help text. I already Know what that verbiage should be.  Now I want to read this help text beside each radio button and verify if it is correct as per the requirement. I will try out all the solutions you have all provided. Thank you all for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Your html has no id's to extract single radio button, so i would suggest to get all the help texts using css selector `".i"` which will give you a list of help texts `["HELP TEXT 1", "HELP TEXT 2"]` and in your testcase you could test all in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findElements() to get all the Help Text's.
Like,

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='i']"));

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

     String text = list.get(i).getText();
     s.o.p(text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `getAttribute("textContent")`, to fetch the help text directly without hovering.

As per the xpath you've added above, you can use the below code to fetch the **first Help text**:

```
String help_text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'apple')]/following-sibling::div[@role='doc']//div[@class='i']")).getAttribute("textContent");
System.out.println(help_text1);
```